# What is the time complexity of adding an element to an empty array by index?

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6, big-o

I know generally speaking that inserting values into an array are constant time. However, I'm struggling to find the time complexity for inserting elements into an array by index for the first time (i.e., initializing element at index[15] on an empty array).

For example:

```
    // input of [-3,5,-2,10]
    const result = [];
    let left = 0;
    let right = array.length - 1;

    for(let i = right; i >= 0; i--) {
        if(array[left] < array[right]) {
            result[i] = array[right];
            right--;
        } else {
            result[i] = array[left];
            left++;
        }
    }
```

Based on the fact that javascript arrays are dynamically sized, they do not behave like arrays in languages I've used in the past. Is this still constant time?

Comment: Dynamically sized arrays still have constant-time access if they're implemented correctly under the hood. Btw, I'd recommend to avoid the sparse arrays and grow the array from the beginning (not backwards).

Comment: @bergi thanks for the reply. Let’s say we’re talking the Chrome implementation. What benefit does growing the array from the beginning have over working backward from the end?